# Can someone explain how I got +2 rep points for editing this question

Tags: support, reputation, editing

Can someone explain how I got +2 rep points for editing this question:

- [Excel Document Size is at 0KB, can't be opened](https://superuser.com/questions/295559/excel-document-size-is-at-0kb-cant-be-opened)

This is someone else's question.

I did not post an answer to the question, and I did not post a comment to the question or answer.

The only thing I did here as make a minor edit to the question, and re-tag the question by adding an additional tag.

I noticed if I view my reputation, I can see:

```
+2  08:23  edit  Excel Document Size is at 0KB, can't be opened
```

But I have never received rep points for editing a question before... is this something new?

Comment: suggested edits have been around since a while. You've suggested [4 edits till date](http://superuser.com/users/144147/kevin-fegan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), of which one was rejected. I presume didn't notice the rep increase back then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When a suggested edit is approved, the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and the total cap is 1,000. Like any other reputation, the +2 is deleted if the edited post is ever deleted.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

So since your rep is below 2000, you get +2 for each suggested edit which is approved.

There is a hard limit of 1,000 reputation earned from approved suggested edits. After that, you can continue to suggest edits, but you won't earn any reputation for getting them approved.

Adding some very useful and obscure info verbatim from @damryfbfnetsi in the comments, there's one exception to the rule that you lose rep if you suggest an approved edit to a later-deleted post: if your suggested edit was to a tag wiki, and the tag is later burninated/manually removed, you get to keep the reputation (it will show up as editing an "orphan wiki")

Comment: Thanks... I did look at my SU "history", and you are correct.. I have gotten points for editing before. I hadn't noticed the points for editing before, and I couldn't find mention of it in the FAQ.

Comment: About the 2000 point cap... Does that mean that once you get to 2,000 points (by non-editing, like Q/A's), that you are no longer eligible to receive points for editing ? ... or are you able to earn 2,000 points for editing regardless of your total points earned otherwise ?

Comment: Once you receive 2000 points, you will no longer receive points for suggesting edits, because you will have normal edit powers.

Comment: Oh, and there's one exception to the rule that you lose rep if you suggest an approved edit to a later-deleted post: if your suggested edit was to a *tag wiki*, and the tag is later burninated/manually removed, you get to keep the reputation (it will show up as editing an "orphan wiki").

Comment: Excellent, thanks @damryfbfnetsi.  I added it to my answer, hope you don't mind if I get some upvotes from it.  At least I won't get any internet points as it's meta :-).

Comment: You should also add that there is a hard limit of 1,000 reputation earned from approved suggested edits. After that, you can continue to suggest edits, but you won't earn any reputation for getting them approved.

Comment: Done.  Also flipped the answer to cwiki, as at this point I think it's more your answer than mine.